# Attribute 'get' - python2

Tags: python, атрибуты, unicode, get

Подскажите направление куда смотреть. При попытке зайти на страницу возникает ошибка,
типа:
--AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'--

контекст:

Traceback указывакт именно на строку ниже.

```
if get_page_number(nav.get('href')) != get_page_number(task.url):
```

буду признателен за "наводку"

Строка получается здесь:

```
def task_initial(self, grab, task): 
    nav = grab.doc.select(u'//a[@class="nounderline" and span[text()="→"]]').text()
    if get_page_number(nav.get('href')) != get_page_number(task.url):
        yield Task('initial', url = nav.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 2):

`nav` - юникодная строка, она не имеет метода `get` и в ней нету `href`, который вы пытаетесь достать.
Смотрите почему у вас в `nav` оказалась строка.

**Обновление**

Похоже, ваша проблема в том, что вы применили метод `.text()`, этого не нужно было делать.

Comment: Спасибо!! вот так работает:

    nav = grab.xpath...etc